# Does the set $[0.1)$ have the least upper bound property?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I know that any proper subset of $[0.1)$ has least upper bound "$a$" in $[0.1)$

If we consider $[0.1)$, which is improper subset of $[0.1)$, its least upper bound is $1$ which does not belong to set.

In that case, does it satisfy least upper bound property?

Comment: HINT: Does the set $[0,1)$ have an upper bound in $[0,1)$ at all? Look carefully at the exact statement of the least upper bound property.

Comment: There is no upper bound in [0.1). it must be 1?

Comment: Oh so, [0.1) is not bounded above, so we exclude this case?

Comment: There you go; yes, that’s right. The LUB property says that every set that has an upper bound has a least upper bound, so it says nothing about a set with no upper bound.

Comment: One more question, does the least upper bound have to be in the set?

Comment: Yes, it does. In this case you’re looking only at elements of the set $[0,1)$. The set has an upper bound in $\Bbb R$, namely $1$, but that’s not relevant to the question here, which takes $[0,1)$ as its ‘universe’.

Comment: You’re very welcome!

Comment: By contrast, consider $[0, 1)$ as a subset of $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$. // Note: comma `,` not period/dot `.` between the endpoints when writing intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is false. $(0,1)$ is a proper subset of $[0,1)$ but does not have an upper bound **in** $[0,1)$, not to say a least one. $\{ 1-\frac{1}{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is even a countable proper subset of $[0,1)$ with no upper bound in $[0,1)$.